# No mapping for GET /me

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this spring boot app and I'm new to spring boot. I have this controller created but it throws 404 and says No mapping for GET /me in the console. I couldn’t find the issue and I need to get this as soon as possible.

Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/Qf5W6MZU

Any other endpoints in this controller also doesn’t work.

```
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.exception.BadRequestException;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.exception.NoContentException;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.exception.UnauthorizedException;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.model.Mentee;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.model.Profile;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.model.Program;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.service.IntrospectionService;
import org.sefglobal.scholarx.util.EnrolmentState;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CookieValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/me")
public class AuthUserController {

    private final IntrospectionService introspectionService;

    public AuthUserController(IntrospectionService introspectionService) {
        this.introspectionService = introspectionService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Profile getLoggedInUser(@CookieValue(value = "profileId", defaultValue = "-1") long profileId)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException, UnauthorizedException {
        return introspectionService.getLoggedInUser(profileId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/programs/mentee")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Program> getMenteeingPrograms(@CookieValue(value = "profileId") long profileId)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException, NoContentException {
        return introspectionService.getMenteeingPrograms(profileId);
    }

    @PutMapping("/mentor/{id}/confirmation")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Mentee confirmMentor(@PathVariable long id,
                                @CookieValue(value = "profileId") long profileId)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException, BadRequestException {
        return introspectionService.confirmMentor(id, profileId);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the application startup log?

Comment: sure @WilliamBurnham https://pastebin.com/Qf5W6MZU

Comment: `2021-03-06 19:51:09.215  INFO 93952 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]` - what does your swagger look like? have you tried /v2/me ?

Comment: swagger doesn’t work for some reason @WilliamBurnham

Comment: what do you see at localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html ?

Comment: your profileId variable should be change from long to String datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I haven’t included the package.